# inserting data into database "table products has no column named accFor (code 1)"

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Ok so i am trying to create an app that takes two values from my interface, one from a text box the other from a spinner and then insert them into the database and display them below the insertion fields.

Error inserting accFor=Personal productname=Ayy
                                                                android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table products has no column named accFor (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO products(accFor,productname) VALUES (?,?)

^^ this is my exact error code

```
package com.kai.todolist;


    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.ContentValues;

public class MyDBManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "productDB.db";
public static final String TABLE_PRODUCTS = "products";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_TODO = "productname";
public static final String COLUMN_FOR = "accFor";

//We need to pass database information along to superclass
public MyDBManager(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_TODO + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_FOR + "TEXT " +
            ");";
    db.execSQL(query);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PRODUCTS);
    onCreate(db);
}

//Add a new row to the database
public void addProduct(Product product){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_TODO, product.getToDo());
    values.put(COLUMN_FOR, product.getAccFor());
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, values);
    db.close();
}

//Delete a product from the database
public void deleteProduct(String productName){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_TODO + "=\"" + productName + "\";");
}

public String databaseToString(){
    String dbString = "";
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE 1";

    //Cursor points to a location in your results
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    //Move to the first row in your results
    c.moveToFirst();

    //Position after the last row means the end of the results
    while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
        if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productname")) != null) {
            dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productname"));
            dbString += "\n";
        }
        c.moveToNext();
    }

    db.close();
    return dbString;
}
```

}

This is my DB handler code where i assume the issue is i do not know where to start on this issue so any help at all would be appreciated. The other class files within my code are Products, which builds the constructor and setters and getters and main activity .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> COLUMN_FOR + "TEXT " +
> ```

You need a space between the column name and its type.

After adding it, you can uninstall your app to get the database recreated.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my issue and has pointed out to me the importance of correct syntax.